# rails 3.2 precompiled assets causes internal server error 500 and log: miss cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a rails 3.2 application in production mode. I have the following settings in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

when i visit application main page i get an (internal server error 500) and in the log all i can  see is

```
cache: [GET /] miss
```

If i change

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

almost everything working fine. But i think it means rake assets:precompile is not working properly in this case, how can i fix it?

Note:
If Sprockets live compile set true (and the site works) and i check firebug net log, i can see that some css or js file are not served, but that is ok for me since they are not really not exists. 
For example i don't use any view specific css or js in costs view and i don't have costs.css or costs.js. Could this be the source of the problem, do i have to create all these files, even if they are empty?

Comment: What does the 500 error show?

Comment: Nothing, only the standard error page. And in the log all i can see cache: [GET /] miss

Comment: I'm having this exact problem and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: what happens if you run locally `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: I did run rake assets:precompile so the above errror appears even then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to a file - that is, it is referenced by Rails- then it should exist.

What happens in the Rails helper is that it will look up the file in the manifest the contains the digests (for production) of all the files. This is going to fail if the file does not exist.

I suggest that you remove any references to files that don't exist.

References to files that you do need should be added to the precompile array.

Comment: When i finally started unicorn_rails with -d i could see some information in the console - but not in production.log or production.error.log - that relevant to the case:

Exception Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError'